# Questions about schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd generated by svcutil.exe

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, asmx, svcutil.exe

I want to distribute the `WSDL` file of my `WCF service` to all the stakeholders. Some will be generating actual web service out of it and a few will be writing client part of it.

When i generated `wsdl`, i found that `schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd` is also generated. My questions are:

1. Is this file/schema necessary in distribution package? (I think, yes.)
2. Is it compliant with the standards?
3. Will there be any interoperability issue? Some stakeholders are on `Java` and `Delphi` platforms.
4. Why the similar schema definition is not generated for the `ASMX` services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *My questions are:*
>
> *1) Is this file/schema necessary in distribution package? (I think, yes.)
>
>   2) Is it compliant with the standards?
>
>   3) Will there be any interoperability issue? Some stakeholders are on Java and Delphi platforms.
>
>   4) Why the similar schema definition is not generated for the ASMX services?*

My answers are:

1) Yes, it's necessary - typically, WCF doesn't generate stuff that's not necessary....
2) Yes, it's **100%** compliant with all WS-* and XML Schema standards.
3) Only if the *other* side of the equation doesn't conform to the documented standards....
4) That's something only the designers at Microsoft can answer ..... I don't know - and frankly I don't care since ASMX is *legacy* technology